# How to typeset music dynamics within normal text

Tags: symbols, music, lilypond

Although it should be possible to create a single musical dynamic symbol (like ***ff*** for *fortissimo* or ***sfz*** for *sforzato*) by creating an in-line lilypond-book fragment, hiding the staff etc. and somehow centering these symbols around an invisible note, I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do the same? Is there a workaround in LaTeX for this which would not require invoking lilypond-book for only putting a simple dynamic symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MusiXTeX uses the normal "bold italic" font for the dynamic marks: `{\textbf{\textit{sfz}}`, but with a small kern between the letters.

It's so not necessary to load all of MusiXTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\muskern}{\kern-.15ex } % what MusiXTeX does

% if only a couple of dynamic marks are needed, this is easier
\newcommand{\sfz}{\textnormal{\textbf{\textit{s\muskern f\muskern z}}}}

% a more general command
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dynmark[1]{{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\put@muskern\next}\/}}
\newcommand{\put@muskern}{\let\put@muskern\muskern}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\sfz X

X\dynmark{sfz}X

X\dynmark{ppp}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I _could_ have looked up their definitions ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Although lilypond's dynamic fonts look by far much more professional, I can live with this solution for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

With [`musixtex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex) maybe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}

fortissimo: \ff, sforzato: \sF

\end{document}
```

[image]

See section 2.17.5 of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/musixtex).

Comment: The `s` of `sf` looks weird, it’s too thin compared to the `f`.

Comment: @doncherry I thought so, too. Looking at examples of typeset notes the s _is_ thinner than the f but to me it seems that the s should be bold and the f even more bold...

Comment: Hi, I tried this method, but unfortunately it seems that MusiXTeX will not work with the `times` package. Inserting `\usepackage{times}` in your code example will halt with an error on my system (TeX Live 2012, Mac OS X 10.6)

Comment: @SiskaÁdám It works if you load `times` _after_ `musixtex`.

Comment: Thank you! It really works. Weird... Anyway, I checked the commands that you suggested and their result has almost nothing to do with real dynamic marks (for example, if you check a forte sign in a printed score, you'd see that they get `fatter' around the dash). egreg's solution is also a bit far from perfect, but somehow they are more acceptable. But thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: @SiskaÁdám as egreg said in his answer: he emulates those by `musixtex` so there should be no visual difference (except for the bold `s`). I agree, though, that the solution is not perfect. A [real music font](http://www.finalemusic.com/usermanuals/finale2012mac/content/Finale/Alternative_music_fonts.htm) surely gives better results.